# changing the way a gallery displays thumbnails

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

In my Wordpress site i have this code which displays the featured-thumbnail large, then the site title then it forms the gallery, then site content (with a back/next nav at the bottom).

content-single.php code

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"<?php post_class('col-md-12'); ?>>
<div class="container">

    <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 1200, 720, true ); //resize & crop the image
    ?>

    <?php if($image) : ?>
    <img class="img-responsive singlepic" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'data-design' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
) );

if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
        $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
        echo '<li class="' . $class . ' data-design-thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>';
    }

}
}
?>

<div class="entry-content">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>

    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'web2feel' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

</div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

I do NOT want a gallery, instead I want the images that are retrieved from the content (the gallery code) to display the images the same way as the featured-thumbnail. Right now it creates a small gallery of images under the title.

Basically, I want it to be large images (as is created by the first php snippet for the featured thumbnail) stacked on each other, then the content-title and then content.

Oddly enough, when I remove the gallery code completely it displays the same way anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the images in the same style as the first one, just change your `foreach` loop to look like this

```php
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'full');
    $image = aq_resize($img_url, 1200, 720, true);        
    ?><img class="img-responsive singlepic" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/><br/><?php
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to change the output. But like I mentioned earlier when I get rid of all the functions the gallery part still shows up, so it must be generated somewhere else and that loop puts it there but I'm not sure

Comment: @user3550879 Could the gallery code be in another file?

Comment: not 100% percent sure, but I was able to fix my problem in the admin by adjusting the image sizes, not sure exactly how it works, but I ain't one to question